# Catkin_make does not build rtabmap_ros¿

Tags: slam, navigation, catkin-make, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, this question is pretty similar to this one: http://answers.ros.org/question/233494/catkin_make-command-doesnt-work/
although in my case I believe the package.xml is correctly set.
My problem is that when I run catkin_make it jumps over the rtabmap_ros package, with no output.
However, if I run **catkin_make --pkg rtabmap_ros** it says that **the "catkin_ws/src/build/rtabmap_ros" folder does not exist**, which of course is true as the command is supposed to build the project. The folder rtabmap_ros is directly downloaded from the repository and it works perfectly in my other computer.
Any ideas about how to proceed?
Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260592/catkin_make-does-not-build-rtabmap_ros%C2%BF/) by [adr_arroyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30197/adr_arroyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try cleanup the catkin build directory and make again:

```
$ rm -r catkin_ws/src/build/*
$ cd catkin_ws
$ catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0